# Is is possible to store a SQLite table in Shared Prefs on Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to take around 100 rows from a table and put them into the shared prefs then delete the database install a fresh and compare values.

I would only need to store 2 values from each row. Column A and column B, but I don't know if this is even possible?

Cheers for any help.

Comment: Err... why don't you copy the new or old (whichever) values to a new temporary table then compare both tables?

Comment: Because I am creating the databases from a sqlite file in the assets folder. I can rename the old table, but I cannot seemingly then append the database to write the newer version in and then compare. At least this is what I have been told and this is the alternative approach I was suggested

Comment: Any app can have more than one associated SQLite DBs, so you might have your old and your new DB live together with two different names. Do your comparisons and when done get rid of the old DB and continue with the new DB.

Answer (score 0):

you can't store a table, but if your table really is that simple (or even if it isn't... I think you can store as much data as you feel like, really), you can transfer it over to a JSON object, stringify and store that. Then pack it back into JSON and over into your new table when you're ready to use it again.

Answer (score 0):

I can also suggest to use a generic lib for abstraction of local store.
Here you have an example:

Use this android lib: https://github.com/wareninja/generic-store-for-android

```
import com.wareninja.opensource.genericstore.GenericStore;

// step.1: transfer data fromt able into GenericStore (aka cache)
String objKey = "mytable01";
int storeType = GenericStore.TYPE_SHAREDPREF;
//keep in mind that you can also use GenericStore.TYPE_MEMDISKCACHE
// which will store on disk cache, which can be faster and better for memory allocation

LinkedHashMap<String, Object> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(); 
// fill in all the data from you table, e.g.
dataMap.put("row1", "val1");

GenericStore.saveObject(storeType, objKey, dataMap, mContext);
// now everything is on stored/cached

// step.2: get data back
dataMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) GenericStore.getObject(storeType, objKey, mContext);
```

*...*
*[Social Coding @ Aspiro TV](http://github.com/AspiroTV)*